# How to set values in birthday dropdown box on a website in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'd like to select specific or random values from dropdown boxes on a website using the built-in web browser module offered by WinForms

[image]

I tried using the code below but it just left a blank space in the box and if submitted then the website would come back with an error saying that the date of birth is not specified.

```
HtmlElement b_day = webBrowser1.Document.All["birthday_day"];
if (b_day != null) {
  var day = rnd.Next(1, 31).ToString();
  b_day. = day;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify but my question is how would I be able to select values from the dropdown box in Winforms?

Comment: I tried using this but it just left the space blank and if submitted then the website would come back with an error saying that the date of birth is not specified.
 `HtmlElement b_day = webBrowser1.Document.All["birthday_day"];
                    if (b_day != null)
                    {
                        var day = rnd.Next(1, 31).ToString();
                        b_day. = day;
                    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set an `HtmlElement` object to a `string`, you need to set the correct attribute of the child `<option>` element. Something like this should work:

```
    private void btnChangeSelection_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElement daySelect = doc.GetElementById("birthday_day");

        if(daySelect != null)
        {
            int newSelection = rnd.Next(1, 31);
            foreach (HtmlElement option in daySelect.Children)
            {
                if(option.InnerText == newSelection.ToString())
                {
                    option.SetAttribute("selected", "true");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here we loop through the `<option>`s available under the `<Select>` element and look for the one that matches to our new random value. We can then set that option's `"selected"` attribute to `"true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Random class](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.8) to generate a random number from an index. In this way it choose randomly from that index with only the member you must use.